# How is this if statement interpreted?

Tags: c#

I saw the code below, which shocked everyone.

How is this code executed?

```
if (!Test.IsXyz == true)
{ }
```

If IsXyz resolves to true but then to false with the ! operator, how is this code interpreted? Because the RHS states true. Would this be:

1) False for LHS | True for RHS == False (From my truth table days)

Assuming the bool resolves to true, I can imagine several wierd ways this code would be understood. What is the official way to the compiler?

Comment: This may be besides the point, but there is really no reason to compare boolean values with true or false. Just do `if (!Test.IsXyz)`.

Comment: I know. That's how I do it too. There is never a need to right == ..., but this was another junior who wrote this.

Answer (score 2):

According to C# operator precedence, this should be evaluated as

((!Test.IsXyz) == true)

thus False (LHS) and True (RHS).

Answer (score 1):

Evaluates to false.

In other words, the code:

```
var Test = new { IsXyz = true };

if (!Test.IsXyz == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
}
```

does not print anything on the screen.

Comment: So what happens if Test.IsXYZ returns false?

Comment: We see "TRUE" on screen, evidently. :-)

Comment: If that = false, then the entire expression is treated as one, so a bit like if (!(Test.IsXyz == true)); , but the reply seems to differ?

Comment: So you're saying that if (!true) and if (!false) both evaluate to false?

Comment: I am saying the same as Joe above; I just tested it with some code, which I posted, to see it working.

Comment: @CesarGon - well you seemed to insert a line of code that the OP doesn't have - maybe that's what's causing the confusion?

Comment: @zebrabox: what line of code is that? If you mean the first line of code in my example, that is necessary for the code to compile and run; I am creating a type with a property to test!

Answer (score 1):

The statement is a more verbose, though equally valid,  equivalent to

```
if (!Test.IsXyz)
{
}
```

So if the result if false then the result of the condition is true.
If the result is true then the result of the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

Order dose not really matter here

as you ether have !( L == R) or (!L) == R, but that equals the same thing as can been seen

```
 L = T : !( T == T) -> !( T ) -> F or (!T) == T -> F == T -> F
```

and

```
 L = F : !( F == T) -> !( F ) -> T or (!F) == T -> T == T -> T
```